# Postioning text and button in a specific position over an image

Tags: html, css, web, web-deployment, bootstrap-4

i wanted to postion a text in (h1) on the image but it affected by the opacity of the image so how can i make it not to get affected by it, i want also to position the button directly under the text but it positiond under the image. the third problem is that there an empty space between the nav bar and div of (the text and the image) as it shown in the screen shot `[screenshot of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/195GQ.png)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400');

body{
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    
}

#top-header {
    text-align: center;
    background: #480000 ;
}
    
.inner {
  
  max-width:960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.nav a {
    
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.txt{

    top: 32%;
    left: 15%;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    color: green;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.main-img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}


.btn {
    top: 40%;
    left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <title></title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row header row-fluid" id="top-header">
           <div class="inner">
               <nav class="nav topnav">
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#protfolio">Protfolio</a>
                <a href="#service">Serviice</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
               </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container-fluid main-div">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <h1 class="txt col-md-4">We Know how to get your Job done</h1>
                    <img  class="img-fluid main-img" src="images/12.jpg" alt="main-image">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Pro</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>

 
      
  </body>

</html>
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to add z-index to as well as image as to layers you want to have on top, this will solve your `opacity` problem,

Second, and third you need change the `position` of the elements which are on top or are at bottom in e.g. i have added absolute position to `.btn` and `.txt`

UPDATE: if you change you css and html to following, you will see wished result:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400');

body{
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;

}

#top-header {
    text-align: center;
    background: #480000 ;
}

.inner {

  max-width:960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.nav a {

    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.txtbutton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 5rem;
    z-index: 100;
}

.txt{
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    color: green;
    font-weight: bolder;
    z-index: 100;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.main-img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}


.btn {
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    line-height: 2.5vw;
    width: 10vw;
    margin-left: 40%;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <title></title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row header row-fluid" id="top-header">
           <div class="inner">
               <nav class="nav topnav">
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#protfolio">Protfolio</a>
                <a href="#service">Serviice</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
               </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid main-div">
            <div class="row">
                <div style = 'width:100%;'>
                  <div class = 'txtbutton'>
                    <h1 class="txt col-md-4">We Know how to get your Job done</h1>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Pro</a>
                  </div>
                    <img  class="img-fluid main-img" src="images/12.jpg" alt="main-image">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i did as you mentioned above and it was helpful but i got another problem, when i use the position absolute and resizing the window the text and the bottom moves to another position as shown here in this screenshot [link](https://imgur.com/Qa0KHvX) also there is an extra white space on right side, i tried to change the position value but i still got the same problem

Comment: to get rid of the white space you will need to make the `width` of parent div 100%, 

to get rid of resizing problem, it is better to wrap button and text in an div, as well as button and text correctly, see update CSS and html files